# Is there a straightforward "mechanical method" to check whether a function is bijective or has an inverse?

Tags: functions

Is there a straightforward "mechanical method" to check whether a function is bijective or has an inverse? I have in mind here something like the truth table as a test for validity in logic.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a computability theory point of view, I suspect it is easy to prove that there is no mechanical way to solve the general problem. From a real-world point of view, the answer below is correct - you really have to prove it is 1-1 and onto. There are are some simple theorems that can help, like if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are bijections, then $g\circ f:A\to C$ is a bijection.

Comment: why dont you try to write what is in your mind in your question?

Comment: Are you asking about specific types of functions or just functions on sets in general? It makes a big difference...

Comment: Should "computability" tag be added? We seem to have some feeling this may be the case.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. I am interested in particular in which of the 16 binary operations on sets have inverses...I am ultimately interested in determining which of the 16 binary operations on sets form groups. I do understand that verifying the axioms is really the way to go. I suspect, however, that there's something about the idea of an inverse I am not understanding precisely. I am an independent learner, and am trying to wrap my head around it anyway I can...

Comment: May I ask you what do exactly mean by mechanical? I am thinking you mean a physical or something method. This subject may be confusing.

Comment: Babak, I specifically had in mind some method that could streamline the checking process by considering all of the relevant binary permutations for set operatiosn, like a truth table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mechanical method is to consider the equations $y=f(x)$ and see how many solutions in $x$ they have for a fixed $y$.

We will say that a  function $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ has an inverse if there exists $g:f(X)\longrightarrow X$ such that $f\circ g=Id_{f(X)}$ and $g\circ f=Id_X$. This is equivalent to $f$ being injective, namely $x_1\neq x_2$ implies $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. In other terms, for every $y\in Y$, the equation $y=f(x)$ has at most one solution in $X$.
If you have the graph of $f$, this is equivalent to the following geometric condition: all the level sets $\{x\in X\;;\; f(x)=y\}$ contain at most one point. In the real-real case, very concretely, it means that every horizontal line has at most one intersection point with the graph of $f$.

Now $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is bijective if it has an inverse and $f(X)=Y$. This is equivalent to injective+onto. This means that for every $y\in Y$, there exists (by onto) exactly one (by injective) solution $x\in X$ to $y=f(x)$. It is denoted by $f^{-1}(y)$ and this defines the inverse function $f^{-1}:Y\longrightarrow X$. Geometrically, this means that the every level set contains exactly one point. In the real-real case, this allows you to take the symmetric of the graph of $f$ with respect to the diagonal $\{x=y\}$ and still obtain the graph of a function: that's the graph of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you Julien, I believe this will suit my purposes. I appreciate it

Comment: @mcmahon.an Great, then. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the method is called *verifying the axioms*.

Given $f:X\to Y$ and suppose $y\in Y$ is some generic point, see if there is always an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ to show it's surjective.

Then suppose that $f(x)=f(x')$ and see if it is absolutely certain that $x=x'$. This would show it is injective.

The truth or falsity of these statements is what needs to be checked.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not a "straight forward mechanical method"

Comment: @mcmahon.an I have trouble imagining something less mechanical :( Maybe you can describe more about what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, from a computability theory point of view, I suspect $\{e:\phi_e\text{ is bijective}\}$ is at least as complex as the halting problem. And that is just a very tiny subset of all functions.

Comment: I should have clarified that I meant something mechanical for binary truth functions. My apologies for not mentioning that!